# Insert mysql table into a div

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem in inserting table from my database to div.

html code:

```
<div class="content">
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT name, surname FROM players";

        $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            if($response) {

            echo' <table align="left"
            cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8" >

            <tr><td align="left"><b>First Name</b></td>
            <td align="left"><b>Last Name</b></td></tr>';

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {

                echo '<tr><td align="left">' .

                $row['imie'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
                $row['nazwisko'] . '</td><td align="left">';

                echo '</tr>';

                }

            echo '</table>';

            } else {

            echo "Couldn't issue database query";

            echo mysqli_error($dbc);

            }

        mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.content {
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
border-bottom: 14px solid #333333;}
```

Is there a way to insert this table to this div? Because when I'm loading this, the table is under my div'content'. The table should be in blank field 'a'.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ44m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correctly indenting your code would have allowed you o spot the error relatively easily - there is an open `td` element. Either remove the last `td` from the echo statement in the loop or add additional `td` pair to first row in table so that they balance ( unless you use `colspan` attributes )

```
<style>
    .content table tr td{ align:left;padding:5px;color:black;background:white; }
</style>


<div class='content'>
    <?php

        $sql = 'select `name`, `surname` from `players`';
        $response = mysqli_query( $dbc, $sql );

        if( $response ) {

            echo "
            <table align='left' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='8' >
                <tr>
                    <td><b>First Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
                </tr>";

            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $response ) ) {
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>{$row['imie']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['nazwisko']}</td>
                </tr>";

            }

            echo "
            </table>";

        } else {
            printf( 'Couldn\'t issue database query: %s', mysqli_error( $dbc ) );
        }

        mysqli_close( $dbc );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Either there was an extra `td` or one missing from first row - either way an unclosed element will throw the flow of html and content all over the place.

Comment: This didn't solved my problem ;/ The table is still outside my div.

Comment: And i don't know why texxt in table is white, while in div it is black.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open `<td>` tag in your code you should close it before closing the `<tr>`